# Unable to rotate an image in clockwise direction in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an image to be rotated in a pivot point(top) through animation. I am able to rotate it in **anti-clockwise direction** by simply changing the **z-rotation value.** **But I want to rotate an image in clockwise direction.**

*If I put a z-rotation value -45 degree, unity converts it to 315 degree and rotates an image in anti-clockwise direction.*

*The image to be rotated has pivot point at top as shown in the figure below.*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could lerp the angle (single float) instaed of the entire rotation. Lerp from your min angle to max angle and just directly set ,rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,angle,0).

There shouldn't be any issue with wrapping from 0 to 360; those are the same rotation (and so are 720 and -360, etc).

(you can't force slerp to go a different direction; it's wired to take the shortest route, just like lerp is (though, understandably, it's harder to tell with lerp))

maybe this code help :

```
 needleHub.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Mathf.LerpAngle(90f, -90f, lerpFactor));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the interpolation type. I remember having almost the exact same problem and fixing it by changing the interpolation to something other than Eulers Angles.

[image]

Comment: As I am trying to **rotate an image through animation,** your answered is nearby my expectation. I made interpolation and choose the Euler Angles (Quaternion) as you said, but fail to get the rotation in clockwise direction.

Comment: try just a Quaternion then.

Answer (score 0):

*Thanks @UriPopov for your reference*. Finally I am able  to rotate an image in clockwise direction through animation. **I change the rotation to EulerAngles(Quaternion)** as said by UriPopov. **But main point to be remember during this animation is that each animation frame should be considered. If one frame is placed empty, then the animation will be in anti-clockwise direction.**

[image]